# Mac cycle backwards through input fields?

Tags: mac, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I've tried searching for this on Google and here but can't seem to find it. I'm looking for a shortcut similar to `Tab` where it goes to the next input field in a form (in Chrome on the web). Is there a way to go backwards instead of forward through the fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> allows you to go backwards through fields in most software.

Similarly, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> goes backwards through browser tabs.